# What ajax framework can i use for organize my javascript code in a single page application entirely server side rendering?

Tags: ajax, frameworks, single-page-application

My website is an ajax single page application with serverside rendering. What are some javascript framework i can use for made a better organization of my javascript code?

Answer (score 0):

BreezeJS you can use for rich data centric apps, which can be used with knockout or angularJS.

I prefer u to use HotTowel SPA template and take a look on this link

http://www.johnpapa.net/spa/

And before asking any questions You should be clear for what you need and why u need. So take your time and look around you will get.

Answer (score 0):

You can look into breezeJS which is used to build rich Data-Centric application, for DOM manipulation you can use some JQueryUI or KendoUI, for dynamic Data bindings which will allow you to change the content of your Views you can prefer Knockout or Angular. Using AngularJS will be much appreciated as it provides rich AngularUI which helps you to change your view to manipulate DOM. Based on type of application you want to develop, you can select from the above suggestions.